# Reload one controller from another controller Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js.I have seen the similar question, but I dont understand that.
I have 2 controllers

```
userControllers.controller('RatingCtrl', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$route)
userControllers.controller('otherProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $http, $location, $window, $timeout,$uibModal, $compile)
```

RatingCtrl and otherProfileCtrl, this two modules are inter-related. My need is that, I have reload RatingCtrl from otherProfileCtrl using `$route.reload();`.Is there is any way to do this without uisng service?plz help

Comment: why don't you want to use a service?

Comment: I think it is difficult.If it is only possible by service, I can try on that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass events from one controller to another in order to achieve this. You would then do something like:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('firstController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
  function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.text = 'Initial text';
    $scope.changeText = function(message) {
      $scope.text = message;
    };

    $rootScope.$on('customEvent', function(event, message) {
      $scope.changeText(message);
    });

  }
]);

app.controller('secondController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'Message from second controller';

    $scope.sendEvent = function() {
      $scope.$emit('customEvent', $scope.message)
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="firstController">
    <h2>This is the fist controller:</h2>
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="secondController">
    <h2>This is the second controller:</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <br>
    <button ng-click="sendEvent()">Send message</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here, the `firstController` listens to events propagated to the `$rootScope`, and the `secondController` sends the message. That is the functionality that you are looking for.

That being said, you would be much better off implementing shared behaviour in a service, since keeping track of all your custom events can be particularly tough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if we are trying to do same thing but in two different apps... what change would we require? means I've 2 controllers in 2 different apps (in same project)

Comment: @NullPointer assuming that you are using Angular 1.*, I can't think of a way to do this properly between two completely independent modules. That being said, if there is a hierarchy between your modules (e.g. one depends on another), the same solution should apply, since there is only one root scope. Though, I'm pretty rusty on my angular.